# How connect local java server and android app by MOBILE internet?

Tags: java, android

I have Java server on my local machine and android app witch connect to this server. I need connect to server use mobile internet. I can connect with WIFI. But my task need mobile internet. I see 1 solution:
1. Deploy server to remote host(but i can't debbug I'll have to use logs and constantly deploy the server)
But i don't want so many. Maybe do somebody know how fix this problem easier?

Comment: Well, what did you put a minus? explain to me

Answer (score 0):

This is a networking problem.  For your local instance you need to setup a static IP address so that your mobile device can connect to it.

By default, your machine is likely firewalled from the Internet.  Once you have a public IP you can connect to your local machine on that port.

There are probably a whole bunch of details about setting up your network to be visible - it really depends on how you are accessing the Internet now.

If you give more details about your network setup, it would be easier to answer your question.

Btw, be careful exposing your local machine - plenty of hacking going on out there.